# many /run files missing after upgrade to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, xorg

I've upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10 and now I am missing the majority of files in /run (my other 11.10 machine has 44 files/folders in /run while the broken system has only 11).

One of the main missing folders is /run/network which makes my networking not work on startup.

Also, possibly related when I do a normal boot I get a blank X screen with an X cursor. After killing X and doing a manual startx, X loads rather well, I can see notifications from notifysend (such as guake and dropbox) and can run some X programs (my autostarted synergy works well).

I should mention that my upgrade did not go smoothly and did something like give an error that the upgrade did not complete successfully, followed by a message that my upgrade did complete successfully.

Comment: Fixing this with a reinstall makes this question very useful to others. Vote to close as too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've "fixed" this by re-installing while leaving the home directory untouched.

Answer (score 1):

The `/run` directory is a `tmpfs` mount.  This means that the contents of the directory do not persist over reboots.  If files are missing from that directory, it means that the programs that write to the directory are not running (or have not been run).  It isn't a case of those programs failing to run due to files not being found in that directory.

You mention that you attempted an upgrade and it did not complete successfully.  Your best bet would be to try and complete that upgrade.  Running the following from the command line will likely get your system into a better state:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Unfortunately, apt-get update followed by apt-get dist-upgrade merely tells me 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. Additionally I've noticed that I still have a /var/run directory when it should be symlinked to /run